# I was interrupted while transferring a very large table. How can I pick it up from where it stopped?

Tags: sql-server, postgresql, count

I wrote a python script to select and insert rows between tables in different databases (from SQL Server to Postgres). the table has around 2000000000 rows and the transfer stopped somewhere in the middle of it. I tried to select the rows with an offset as the number of rows already transferred. But count(*) takes up too much server resources and the server becomes unresponsive when I try. (memory usage rises from 100MB to ~8GB in a very short time)

I'm wondering if there's a way to pick up the transfer from where it stopped. It took around 3 days to transfer the number of rows I currently have in Postgres.

Thanks.

---

Also, I know the approximate number of the rows. So maybe I can do something like this: if there are approximately 12392320 rows, delete everything after the 12390000th row and just start from 12390001. Is something like that possible?

Comment: This will all depend on whether the rows were transferred in an ORDER. Any idea if they were? You'd probably be better off dumping the data to a .csv file and bulk loading that in, rather than doing a select/insert using python. A bulk load will be much faster.

Comment: Phil: It was transferred without an ORDER. I might try the csv option, but I'm not sure if it works well with datetime objects, texts, unicode, nulls, and etc.

Comment: Phil: Also, the two databases are in a local network and can transfer around 5000 rows per second. That's fast enough for me although it can be faster. Thanks.

Comment: This looks like an OK way to push the data: http://www.postgresonline.com/journal/index.php?/archives/103-Using-Microsoft-SQL-Server-to-Update-PostgreSQL-Data.html - There might be a nice Postgres/ODBC way to do it too

Comment: RE, your edit. That's why I asked if they'd been transferred in a specific order. If repeating the query again (with an offset) would guarantee the same order, that would work. I guess it depends if the source table has changed

Comment: The source table did not change. I think, although I did not use an ORDER, the outputs are always in the same order. I'm not sure what the default order is determined by. I'm a python programmer and have a lot to learn about this topic. I'd prefer to continue with the python script I wrote, if possible, because that way, at least I can control the inputs and outputs more than with text files.

Comment: Probably best if one of the SQL Server people can confirm how SQL Server does tablescans & if the data will /definitely/ be returned in the same order.

Comment: You cannot "delete everything after the 12390000th row" because the rows are not ordered. It might seem like they are ordered, but they are not, and a `delete` is precisely the sort of operation that will expose that underlying fact.

Comment: please post your *exact* `count(*)` query - there is no reason why a simple count(*) would use lots of memory unless there are a huge number of writes going on in the rest of the database.

Comment: Do you have a key on the Postgres table that can be used to track where you are?

Comment: gbn: Yes. There is a primary key.

Comment: I did this: `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM schema.tablename`

Comment: sorry, is the key an ascending autonumber too?

Comment: It is not ascending autonumber

Answer (score 8):

An alternative view:

Are you really using inserts for 2B rows?  You might be better off [bulk loading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/758945/whats-the-fastest-way-to-do-a-bulk-insert-into-postgres) the data.  2B rows shouldn't take 3 days unless they are spectacularly wide.

Also, [pg_bulkload](http://pgbulkload.projects.postgresql.org/) might be of interest for this.

Comment: Will it work with loading from a non-postgres DB? I have the db structure and keys converted from SQL Server to Postgres, so I just need to copy the contents.

Comment: You should be able to export to a series of .CSV files (or some other suitable format).  Then import them using the bulk load facility.  It will be some orders of magnitude faster than select/inserts.